# Insert List of words into a Word / create sentences

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a list of words:

cat

dog

bird

I have one static sentence: "the [variable] is happy"

I need to generate:

the cat is happy

the dog is happy

the bird is happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Public Sub test()
   Dim MySentence As String, MyWords As String, MyWordsAR() As String, i As Long
   
   MySentence = "The XXX is happy"
   MyWords = "cat dog fish robin frog"
   MyWordsAR = Split(MyWords, " ")
   
   For i = LBound(MyWordsAR) To UBound(MyWordsAR)
      ActiveDocument.Content = ActiveDocument.Content & vbCrLf & Replace(MySentence, "XXX", MyWordsAR(i))
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: i made some edits if i have two sentences.  Does that look ok?  what if i want to add a word separating each series ?  the input list might be over 1000 lines long.

Comment: At a quick glance yes, your suggested edit is fine, if it suits what you want (a block of lines of sentence 1 followed by a block of sentence2 lines.  BTW If you're happy with the answer it'd be great if you could mark it as accepted